# Loop through condition and append to string in php?

Tags: php, string, for-loop

Am writing some content to a file, I store all the content in a variable. Some parts of the file content need to be repeated with  some minor changes, those changes are stored in a variable and I need to run a for loop for that change.

See the following code sample,

```
$looped_valueArray; //this is an array i need to loop the content in $looped_value 
                    //to show all the values
$content = 'sample content '. $looped_value.'
fdgdf';
```

I could not loop write a `forloop` appending to a string like

```
$content = 'sample content '. 
        foreach($looped_valueArray as $looped_value) $looped_value;.'fdgdf';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi follow this scripts if you would like append your content in a variable:

```
$content ="sample content ";
foreach($looped_valueArray as $looped_value){
$content .=$looped_value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a loop directly in the string. Either define a separate function that loops through the values, or, in the above example, you could just use implode():

`$content = 'sample content ' . implode("", $looped_valueArray) . 'fdgdf';`